# vertically aligning div inside div not working

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

How come the div's inside #inner are not vertically aligning? Do note that I am using IE 8 and CSS, not CSS3 if that makes a difference.
This is my html.

```
<div class="Content">

    <div id="home">
        <div id="inner">
                <div id="stuff">HeadingOne</div>
                <div>HeadingTwo</div>
                <div>HeadingThree</div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

This is my CSS

```
    #inner div {
         display: inline;
    }

    #home #inner {
        margin: 0px auto;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    #home {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align:center;
    }
```

As you can see, I tried making display: table-cell; and then doing vertical-align: middle but it didn't work. Any idea why? And yes, I need the '#inner div' displays to be inline. I want the there div's inside #inner to be inline and in the center of Content.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to end up with?

Comment: @andi I want the there div's inside #inner to be inline and in the center of Content.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/c9zPc/ So this ISN'T what you want?....

Comment: I don't understand the difference between what you have and what you want.  Seems like you have what you want already.

Comment: @andi Hm okay seems like I have to go through my entire code again because something seems to be making it not vertically align properly.

Comment: @andi wait I want the divs inside #inner to vertically align, not just horizontally align. When I copy just the code I showed you, paste it in a new notepad file and then save it as a .html file and open it in IE 8, it doesn't vertically align to the exact middle of the page.

Comment: @A.0 okay one sec, I can't view the jsfiddle right now for some reason. I'm going to try to download another browser and open it with another browser, im using IE 8 at the moment.

Comment: hey y don't you apply </br> after each <div> that will work for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

You are using bad the `display` property. Use this CSS:

```
#home {
    display: table;
    text-align:center;
}    
#home #inner {
    display:table-cell;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#inner div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

You can review this link with the example in IE8 http://jsfiddle.net/rd2Hc/18/embedded/result/

Comment: Hm I need the display of #inner div to be inline.  I tried your code and it still doesn't vertically align the #inner div's.

Comment: AM ok so the #inner divs vertically aligned inside what? can you make a fiddle showing the problem?